# How can I find messages in Graylog based on level (syslog severity/priority)

Tags: rsyslog, graylog2

I'm storing data from Drupal into syslog into Graylog. I'd like to find all messages based on their severity (what Graylog seems to call level).

Here's a screenshot of some messages showing the "Level" field. These all happen to be Notices, but the search I entered is finding the word "Notice" in the message field, not in the Level field.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since the Drupal logs are going through syslog (and Drupal's watchdog severity matches [RFC 5424 severity levels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog#Severity_levels)) the levels you're looking for are stored in graylog by their numeric ID, e.g. 0-7.

So, use search "level:5" to find messages with a severity level of notice.

I found this notation out by clicking into a Graylog message and then clicking on the level field. Clicking on a field within a message highlight will put that field into the search section where you can see the notation required.

Comment: is there any plugin to parse the level number to a more easy value, like Warn, Error, Info, and so on ?

Comment: @pedrorijo91 You can use the "Syslog Serverity Mapper" which you can find in the "Decorator" tab (tested with Graylog 3.1).

Answer (score 11):

I don't know if this is going to be useful or not, but Graylog identifies level in a numeric fashion according to [syslog system](https://docs.delphix.com/docs534/system-administration/system-monitoring/setting-syslog-preferences/severity-levels-for-syslog-messages).

- 0=Emergency
- 1=Alert
- 2=Critical
- 3=Error
- 4=Warning
- 5=Notice
- 6=Informational
- 7=Debug

Based on that, to search for a Warning message your search in Graylog can be as simple as:

```
level:4
```

in the search bar of Graylog. You may also use  less that expression like:

```
level: <=4
```