# display graylog level string

Tags: logback, graylog

When I search for logs in graylog and display the log level I only see the number of the level. I'd like to be able to see the corresponding string (Alert[1] or Error[7]) like it is displayed in the images of these two links:

- https://www.graylog.org/resources/gelf-2/#specs
- [How can I find messages in Graylog based on level (syslog severity/priority)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29564739/how-can-i-find-messages-in-graylog-based-on-level-syslog-severity-priority)

I am logging through logback with the message pattern:

`<pattern>%relative%thread%mdc%level%logger%msg</pattern>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a known issue in Graylog 1.1 or newer. From the issue (https://github.com/Graylog2/graylog2-web-interface/issues/1630):

> In the search result view and message detail view the special field 'level' get rendered with the numeric value from message.fields and not message.formatted_fields.
>
> e.g. instead of Error [3] only 3 will be rendered.

Comment: To be honest I wanted to add it as a comment to the answer, but as you can see my karma is not enough.  

I edited the answer to provide more information, as suggested.

Comment: Here have some karma then.